# object becomes null after assigning it's innerhtml property

Tags: c#, html, geckofx

I am trying to replace some code inside an html element. At one point, I add a  elements around pieces of text within a webpage. At other I need to remove it (it's a simple search engine in geckofx-based browser)

```
if (element.OuterHtml.Contains(spanStyle))
    if (element.Parent != null)
    {
         string oldHtml = element.OuterHtml;
         string newHtml = oldHtml.Replace(spanStyle, "").Replace("</span>", "");
         element.Parent.InnerHtml = newHtml;
    }
```

The problem is that I cannot replace OuterHtml of the element - instead, I am trying to replace InnerHtml of it's parent.

However, the element.Parent becomes null as soon as `element.Parent.InnerHtml = newHtml;` is executed, and the OuterHtml of the element still contains the span element.    I have even tried replacing the text content of the element.Parent.InnerHtml to see if the problem is in removing tags, but apparently it does not make a difference - as soon as I assign the `element.Parent.InnerHtml`, `element.Parent` becomes null.

Cheers!

Bartosz

Comment: Can you post the code for spanStyle?

Comment: @HimBromBeere - sure, that's `<span style=\"background-color: gold;\">`. The variables newHtml and oldHtml always look all OK. And the element.Parent becomes null even if I use something like `element.Parent.RemoveChild(element);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `InnerHtml` of the elements parent it is obvious that the child element is not longer the child of the parent and therefore `element.Parent` becomes `null`. Have you tried to store `element.Parent` in a temporary variable like this?

```
var parent = element.Parent;
...
element.Parent.InnerHtml = newHtml;
...
// do something with the variable parent here which should not be null
```

Comment: Hi Robert, thanks - Actually, I tried that, but this did not really solve my problem. My goal is to replace the element.OuterHtml which is something like `<span style=\"background-color: gold;\">higlighted string</span>` with `higlighted string` and since I cannot assign OuterHtml, I wanted to try with innerHtml of the parent, which appears to be the same...

Comment: The problem is that when you remove the `span`-Tags, `element` is no longer existent as `element` IS the `span`-Tag. If `element.Parent` is a tag like `<root>` you have to search this node/element again to access it.

Comment: For example if the XML looks like this: `<root><span style="background-color: gold;">higlighted string</span></root>`, `element` is the `span`-Tag and `element.Parent` is the `root`-Tag. Now if you do: `element.Parent.InnerHtml = "higlighted string";`, `element` is no longer existent as the `span`-Tag was removed. To access the `root`-Tag you have to find it again, e.g. with the XPath `//root`.

Comment: Actually this is the reason why you can't change `OuterXml`. Cause `OuterXml` contains the tag of the current element itself. A change to `OuterXml` would result in the situation that the element itself is no longer existent and becomes invalid. So your approach isn't possible in a logical way.